# Pasar dato de Actividad a Clase

Tags: android, clase

Compañeros, estoy enviando valores a mi Servicio.class desde la siguiente actividad:

[image: pimactivity]

Pero en servicio.class no me toma el getIntent (al ser una clase)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Necesito pasar datos de PimActivity a servicio* y luego en servicio enviar datos a un tercerActivity. (Al tercer activity lo envio con putextra. Eso esta resulelto)

Comment: 2 cosas, lo primero deberías de poner el código como texto y no como imagen ya que así no podemos copiarlo para ver lo que pasa. Segundo, extiendes de AccessibilityService y no de Service por algo?

Comment: Las imagenes son a modo de ejemplo. Necesito enviar un valor desde una actividad a una clase. Simplemente eso.

Comment: y porque heredas de AccessibilityService? Si lo hicieses de Service, el intent te vendría en el método onStartCommand

Comment: porque el Service.java es un servicio de accesibilidad que lee las respuestas ussd. Sin extenderlo, no podria usar los metodos necesarios.

Comment: Puedes escribir los datos necesarioos en un fichero y leerlos al arrancar el servicio, o tambiñen podrías declarr una variable global a la que puedes acceder desde el servicio. Si npoder recoger el intent son las 2 maneras que se me ocurren

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15899750/5453049

Comment: @AldazDev acostumbra agregar el código como texto en lugar de en imágenes en tus preguntas.  te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,

Answer (score 0):

Si el servicio extiene de `Service` :

```
 extends Service {
```

Los valores que envias a través del `Intent`

```
   Intent i = new Intent(this, Servicio.class);
   i.putExtra("cantidadMonedas", stCantMonedas);
   startService(i);
```

deben ser obtenidos en el Servicio dentro de  `onStartCommand()`

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("cantidadMonedas")) {
                String valorObtenido = intent.getStringExtra("cantidadMonedas");
            }

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```